# How to properly match a java method invocatin with Antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I am writing a simple program that analyses a method body (written in Java 7) and lists all the method invocations it has.

For starters, I want to be able to detect calls to static methods, calls on local variables and class member variables:

```
class TestSubject {
    String m;

    void alpha() {
        String l;

        l.charAt(0); // local
        m.contains(""); // member
        String.valueOf(0);  // static
        bravo().valueOf(0); // local on method
    }

    String bravo() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

A method invocation will generally look like foo.bar(). I am currently struggling with matching this pattern. This is the (relevant) part of the grammar that is supposed to describe this:

```
expression
    :   primary
    |   expression '.' Identifier
    |   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
```

1. How can this grammar generate something that looks like 'foo.bar()'? After all the only thing that is allowed after the '.' is an Identifier. hich part of the grammar describes 'bar()' that comes after a '.'?
2. To the point: what is the best way to match a method invocation?

Currently I have something along:

```
@Override
public void enterExpression(@NotNull JavaParser.ExpressionContext ctx) {
    if(ctx.expression() != null && ctx.expression().size() == 1 && right(ctx) != null){
        // This is something that may be a method invocation
    }
}
```

To catch *static* invocations, but this is clearly weak..

I already have a symbol table (a hash of class member variables, method local variables and method arguments at this stage). My problem is matching a method invocation. I have trouble understanding how the Java.g4 grammar generates methods + what is the best way to get to expressions of the form `x.y()` (I will make the necessary interpretation later)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4

Comment: The Java language reference contains a grammar for Java which you'll have to parse in full for achieving what you want to achieve. - I think that you are heading straight into a multi-multi-year project, so you'd better reconsider why you think yoi need to do this in the first place.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind, I am already using Java.g4 grammar. I already have a lexer and parser.

Comment: @laune, it is not that big a deal... just looking for the correct usage pattern

Comment: Here's a few more that aren't "that big a deal": `("A" + " " + "B").split( " " )[0]`, `new BigInteger( "123" ).divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN)[1]`, `s.replaceAll( "a", "" + s.charAt( s.indexOf( 'c' ) ) )`. And I've seen worse...

Comment: @laune, the complexity of the parts that constitute the invocation has absolutely no significance. They all follow the same x.y() pattern. My question is about how to capture it properly. Moreover, I am not trying to solve the general case, in my case I can be assured that the target is either a type of a class (in case of a static method) or an instance variable (member, local or a method argument).

Comment: Even if you restict the syntax of the *call*, the (necessarily) unrestricted syntax of the call's arguments will make you sweat. - Do you rule out the highly recommended idiom `"stringliteral".equals( s )`? Fie!

Comment: Yes, the expression rule should be the correct rule, yet hard to see how it could match.  Best suggestion would be to add print statements/breakpoints to the enterEveryRule & exitEveryRule methods and parse and walk a minimal source code sample.  That will show you the exact path matched.  (Look at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test for examples of how to do quick test runs -- BaseTest.java makes it easy to test snippets.)

Comment: @GRosenberg, good idea! It ultimately lead me to the answer. Please post as answer to get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the expression rule should be the correct rule, yet hard to see how it could match.

Best suggestion would be to add print statements/breakpoints to the enterEveryRule & exitEveryRule methods and parse and walk a minimal source code sample. That will show you the exact path matched.

Look at github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test for examples of how to do quick test runs -- BaseTest.java makes it easy to test snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you simply cannot distinguish static and instance method calls purely based on the syntax / parse tree.  For example, given the following declaration:

```
    public class MyClass {
        public static void method(){};
    }
```

then both of the following calls are static method calls:

```
    MyClass.method();  // static method call
    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    m.method();        // static method call!!
```

To reliably distinguish static and instance method calls, you need to:

1. Analyse the class whose method is being called, to find out which methods are static and which aren't.
2. Analyse the calls to determine whether you have an *expression* or a *type name* before the `.`.
3. If you have a *type name*, then the method has to be `static`.
4. If you have an *expression* you need to determine the expression's type.
5. Given the expression type, and given that that type is a class, you need to perform method signature matching to determine the best match.
6. Finally, you look to see if the matched method is `static` or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are reference implementations of Antlr4 grammars here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java

1. How can this grammar generate something that looks like 'foo.bar()'? After all the only thing that is allowed after the '.' is an Identifier. Which part of the grammar describes 'bar()' that comes after a '.'?

   If you look at [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L499) line:

   ```
   expression
      :   primary
      |   expression '.' Identifier
      // ...
      |   expression '(' expressionList? ')' #FunctionInvocation // <-- this is the line that catches all function invocations
   ```

   you'll see that `foo.bar` is an `expression`. And `foo.bar` `(` `)` is also an expression.
2. To the point: what is the best way to match a method invocation?

   Catch the line marked above.

Comment: I am already using this grammar. It has no mention of #FunctionInvocation token anywhere in the file. Note that I need the entire statement- including the target instance.

Comment: I added the # part to make it simpler to access this option during post processing.

Comment: In retrospect, I see that your answer made sense but was not clear enough.